# Custom Marker Cluster (From Google Maps API) not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am trying to set up custom marker clusters for my google maps API integration, but its rendering incorrectly:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be a problem with my image, which looks fine:

[image]

Here is my code for the clusterer:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            maxZoom: 18,
            imagePath: 'images/m'});
```

And here is my file tree:

[image]

Do you know what might be going wrong?

Comment: it looks like it is background image and it is being displayed repeatedly. If that's the case try the following css rule background-repeat : no-repeat; background-size : contain

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

It seems that the image was smaller than the cluster square, which for some reason renders like this. A working fix was to create a file/canvas with the same size as the cluster (for example 56x56 for m2), while keeping the marker centered in it in the desired size.

Thanks for taking a look anyway.